# error in balebot payment message

Tags: python, websocket, bots, messenger

I want to create a simple payment message in my balebot but it's the result:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'balebot.models.messages.banking.money_request_type'
```

I dont have any idea about it! can any one help me?

Comment: http://www.daveoncode.com/2017/03/07/how-to-solve-python-modulenotfound-no-module-named-import-error/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just fix in 1.1.2 update for balebot. try to get new version of balebot by pip.

```
pip install balebot==1.1.2
```